# Google Play Store App like Rating bar in Android

Tags: android, material-design, ratingbar

I want to create a Rating bar exactly like Google Play store, same like below image,

[image]

I have tried with multiple libraries found on github,
But still has some issues like in one star size is fixed and in other selected start border color is not changing,

Can anyone pls help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a way?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) yourRatingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#e7c31b"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for filled stars
stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#e7c31b"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for half filled stars
stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#c2c2c2"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // for empty stars
```

It's look like this:
[image]